# How do I un-remember Android Studio setting

Tags: android-studio

I had just installed Dart and was following the first app tutorial for flutter. I opened the `profile/AndoidManifest.xml` file.

I clicked the "Open for editing in Android Studio" text. It showed me three choices: "This Window", "New Window", and "Cancel", and a check box to "Remember, don't ask again".

I foolishly checked "Remember, don't ask again" and clicked "New Window". "New window" is not the choice I wanted to make permanent. Neither was "This window", I should have clicked cancel, but that's beside the point.

I cannot figure out how to un-remember this setting choice. I have searched through `File->Settings` without finding anything that seems applicable.

Comment: Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561)

Comment: Done. Most of what I highlighted is literal text from the Android Studio UI. How should those be formatted to distinguish them from my own text.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with just quotes. But if you *want* to highlight it additionally, you can use bold or italic. Just be careful [not to abuse it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141091/332043) or otherwise add too much bold text.(excessive and/or unnecessary formatting degrades readability, and kinda defeats the purpose of especially highlighting-based markdown)

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it via that steps.
File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Project Opening

And you can tick Ask Button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpBN1.png)